# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estuve leyendo las demás preguntas sobre este tema pero no pude dar con mi problema, en el debugger del navegador(chrome) me encuentro con esto, creo que se mezcla el json con html pero no puedo resolverlo:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: accion in **C:\xampp\htdocs\agendaPHP\inc\modelos\modelo-contacto.php** on line **3**
{"id":"3","accion":"borrar"}

les dejo el codigo php

```
<?php

if ($_POST['accion']=='crear'){
    //creara un nuevo registro en la base de datos
    require_once('../funciones/db.php');

    //validar las entradas
    $nombre= filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $empresa= filter_var($_POST['empresa'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $telefono= filter_var($_POST['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    try {
        $stm = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO contactos (nombre, empresa, telefono) VALUES (?,?,?)" );
        $stm->bind_param("sss", $nombre, $empresa, $telefono);
        $stm->execute();
        if ($stm->affected_rows==1) {//si hay uno afectado
            $respuesta=array(
                'respuesta'=> 'correcto',
                'datos'=> array(
                    'nombre'=>$nombre,
                    'empresa'=> $empresa,
                    'telefono'=>$telefono,
                    'id_insertado'=>$stm->insert_id
                )
            );
        }
        $stm->close();
        $db->close();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $respuesta=array(
            'error'=> $e-getMenssage()
        );

    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}

if ($_GET['accion']=='borrar'){

    echo json_encode($_GET); 
}
```

el primer if me funciona sin problemas, ahora cuando agregue el if del get(que es donde va a entrar para ejecutarse la funcion que estoy usando) me marca un error en la linea 3 del php.

les dejo la funcion javascript:

```
 function eliminarContacto(e) {
    if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('btn-borrar')){
        //tomar el id
        const id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');

        //preguntar al usuario
        const respuesta= confirm('Estas seguro');

        if(respuesta){
            //llamado a ajax
            //crear el objeto
            const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

            //abrir la conexion
            xhr.open('GET', `inc/modelos/modelo-contacto.php?id=${id}&accion=borrar`, true);

            //leer la respuesta
            xhr.onload= function() {
                if (this.status===200) {
                    const resultado= JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(resultado);
                }
            }
            //enviar la peticion
            xhr.send();
        }   
    }
}
```

hace 2 días que estoy con esto sin poder solucionarlo, gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que dentro del mismo script esperas recibir `accion` por `$_POST` o por `$_GET` y, ya que lo estás manejando por AJAX, realiza todas las peticiones con el mismo método. O bien, en PHP crea una variable `$accion` y asigna el valor antes de comenzar con las condiciones:

Puedes tomar `accion` desde [$_REQUEST](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.request.php), ahí están todas las variables recibidas, ya sea por GET, POST y COOKIE y lo más recomendable es hacerlo por asignación ternaria, para garantizar que la variable siempre tendrá un valor, además de evitar el error *Undefined index...*

```
$accion = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

if ($accion == 'crear'){
    //creara un nuevo registro en la base de datos
    require_once('../funciones/db.php');

    //validar las entradas
    $nombre= filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $empresa= filter_var($_POST['empresa'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $telefono= filter_var($_POST['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    try {
        $stm = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO contactos (nombre, empresa, telefono) VALUES (?,?,?)" );
        $stm->bind_param("sss", $nombre, $empresa, $telefono);
        $stm->execute();
        if ($stm->affected_rows==1) {//si hay uno afectado
            $respuesta=array(
                'respuesta'=> 'correcto',
                'datos'=> array(
                    'nombre'=>$nombre,
                    'empresa'=> $empresa,
                    'telefono'=>$telefono,
                    'id_insertado'=>$stm->insert_id
                )
            );
        }
        $stm->close();
        $db->close();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $respuesta=array(
            'error'=> $e-getMenssage()
        );

    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
} elseif($accion == 'borrar') {
    echo json_encode($_GET); 
}
```

Comment: Nunca había usado un request, siempre se aprende algo nuevo, muchas gracias.